# ¿Cómo obtener el resultado de la ejecución de una función Oracle en Codeigniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter-3

Buenos días, tengo dificultades al obtener el resultado de una función Oracle que retorna un NUMBER, el código que actualmente uso en el modelo es el siguiente:

```
public function obtenerIdEnvio()
    {
        $sql = "DECLARE
                  retorno NUMBER;
                BEGIN  
                  retorno := obtener_consecutivo;
                END; ";
        return $this->db->query($sql)->row();
    }
```

Hasta ahí se ejecuta bien, no sale error ni nada y si es ejecutado por sql plus se obtiene efectivamente el dato, pero NO puedo obtener dicho resultado que corresponde a un NUMBER.

Definición de la función:

```
create or replace function obtener_consecutivo()
  return number
 is
 begin 
   return 100;
 end;
```

¿De que forma puedo obtener dicho resultado en una barvariable con Codeigniter?, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ese codigo solo ingresa el resultado de una funcion en una variable. Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
$sql = SELECT obtener_consecutivo FROM DUAL;
```

y en codeigniter atrapas el resultado con el nombre de la funcion:

```
return $this->db->query($sql)->row()->obtener_consecutivo;
```

si fuera por ejemplo un sequence... seria algo asi:

```
$sql = SELECT secuencia.nextval FROM DUAL;
return $this->db->query($sql)->row()->nextbal;
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda. Saludos!